# Автотревога о войне откатов срабатывает зря

Tags: дефект, тревоги, инструменты-модератора

Мне кажется, что тревога о войне откатов не должна срабатывать, если оба отката сделаны одним и тем же пользователем - не воюет же он сам с собой.

[image: скриншот]

На самом деле, я после первого отката заметил, что правок было больше, чем я думал, и большая часть из них полезные, поэтому откатил ещё раз, чтобы вернуть как было. После возврата [к вопросу](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/9531/revisions) (до изменения заголовка) тревога уже стояла.

Comment: @Suvitruf, а зачем картинку в цитату, если у неё и так есть рамка?

Comment: Не помню, вроде было тут обсуждение, чтоб все картинки в цитаты оборачивали 

Comment: @Suvitruf, не помню такого. Я думал, мы оборачиваем только те, которые сливаются с текстом.

Comment: Ага, это было основной причиной.

Comment: @Suvitruf оцитирование картинок позволяет их быстрее отличать от элементов UI. Ну и по сути это и есть «цитата», ведь информация на картинке сгенерирована сайтом, а не автором сообщения.

Answer (score 1):

Так ведь война откатов, а не пользователей. Формальность соблюдена!

А если серьёзно, то кмк подобные откаты одним и тем же участником уже достаточно подозрительны и редки, а стало быть модератору вовсе не помешает посмотреть на эту ситуацию более пристальным взглядом. Может быть таким "хитрым" образом автор пытается поднять свой вопрос в списке, не привнося в него по факту ни какой новой полезной информации (или удаляя действительно ошибочную и/или излишнюю).

В общем, я за то, чтобы эта автотревога продолжала работать как и сейчас в данном случае.

Хотя, конечно, не стоило бы доверять обработку этой тревоги тому же участнику, который по сути к ней и привёл (хотя формально её и поднял Дух). Это как инспектор, расследующий дело, в котором сам является преступником.

Comment: Модераторы могут обрабатывать тревоги на собственных сообщениях, но обычно так не делают. В движок вообще подобные проверки не заложены. По поводу поднимания вопроса вверх - есть же гораздо более простой способ с правкой - хоть тупо пробел в конец добавить.